# How to set the number of digits after the decimal place displayed in a numpy float?

Tags: python, numpy

[Per the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions) I set the number of digits of precision for printing a numpy float to 8 and expected to see
`1.12345679` from this code but did not:

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision=8)

x = np.float_(1.123456789)

print x
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: or perhaps: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html

Comment: `set_printoptions` controls how the arrays are displayed that's why it is not working, if you print that as `print(np.array([np.float_(1.123456789)]))`. It will give you the right result. Your best bet seems to be string formatting during print.

Comment: `x = np.float_(round(1.123456789, 8))`

Comment: rounding functions change the data but do not force the representation to be 8 places after the deceimal unconditionally.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have suggested you could use numpy.around.

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision=4)

x = np.float_(1.123456789)
print x

x = np.around(x, 8)
print x
```

This outputs:

```
1.123456789
1.12345679
```